# reading a CSV into a Datatable without knowing the structure

Tags: c#, .net, csv, datatable

I am trying to read a CSV into a datatable.

The CSV maybe have hundreds of columns and only up to 20 rows.

It will look something like this:

```
+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------+---+
|  email1  |     email2      |   email3    | email4  | … |
+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------+---+
| ccemail1 | anotherccemail1 | 3rdccemail1 | ccemail |   |
| ccemail2 | anotherccemail2 | 3rdccemail2 |         |   |
| ccemail3 | anotherccemail3 |             |         |   |
| ccemail4 | anotherccemail4 |             |         |   |
| ccemail5 |                 |             |         |   |
| ccemail6 |                 |             |         |   |
| ccemail7 |                 |             |         |   |
| …        |                 |             |         |   |
+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------+---+
```

i am trying to use [genericparser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F) for this; however, i believe that it requires you to know the column names.

```
string strID, strName, strStatus;
using (GenericParser parser = new GenericParser())
{
    parser.SetDataSource("MyData.txt");

    parser.ColumnDelimiter = "\t".ToCharArray();
    parser.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
    parser.SkipStartingDataRows = 10;
    parser.MaxBufferSize = 4096;
    parser.MaxRows = 500;
    parser.TextQualifier = '\"';

    while (parser.Read())
    {
      strID = parser["ID"];  //as you can see this requires you to know the column names
      strName = parser["Name"];
      strStatus = parser["Status"];

      // Your code here ...
    }
}
```

is there a way to read this file into a datatable without know the column names?

Comment: CSV means really comma separated? Is there always a header or not? `…` meant that there might be more columns and you don't knwo how many or that this column is empty?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes there will always be a header

Comment: @Blam can you elaborate please? how do i know when to stop [0][1]...[243]..? i dont know in advance how many columns there are.

Comment: Is there a parser.columns or something like that?

Answer (score 8):

It's so simple!

```
        var adapter = new GenericParsing.GenericParserAdapter(filepath);
        DataTable dt = adapter.GetDataTable();
```

This will automatically do everything for you.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the source code, and you can access the data by column index too, like this

```
var firstColumn = parser[0]
```

Replace the 0 with the column number.
The number of  colums can be found using

```
parser.ColumnCount
```

Comment: thank so much. blam suggested the same thing above, but i do not know in advance how many columsn there are

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with that `GenericParser`, i would suggest to use tools like [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx), [`FileHelpers`](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/quick_start.html) or this [`CSV-Reader`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader).

But this simple manual approach should work also:

```
IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
String header = lines.First();
var headers = header.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
{
    tbl.Columns.Add(headers[i]);
}
var data = lines.Skip(1);
foreach(var line in data)
{
    var fields = line.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    DataRow newRow = tbl.Rows.Add();
    newRow.ItemArray = fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i used generic parser to do it. 
On the first run through the loop i get the columns names and then reference them to add them to a list

In my case i have pivoted the data but here is a code sample if it helps someone

```
        bool firstRow = true;
        List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
        List<Tuple<string, string, string>> results = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

        while (parser.Read())
        {
            if (firstRow)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < parser.ColumnCount; i++)
                {
                    if (parser.GetColumnName(i).Contains("FY"))
                    {
                        columnNames.Add(parser.GetColumnName(i));
                        Console.Log("Column found: {0}", parser.GetColumnName(i));
                    }
                }
                firstRow = false;
            }

            foreach (var col in columnNames)
            {
                double actualCost = 0;
                bool hasValueParsed = Double.TryParse(parser[col], out actualCost);
                csvData.Add(new ProjectCost
                {
                    ProjectItem = parser["ProjectItem"],
                    ActualCosts = actualCost,
                    ColumnName = col
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would argue a generic parser is reinventing the wheel a bit. There are many pre-rolled CSV parsers that will work without knowing column names. It may be helpful to less experienced users if you define pivoting, or provide an example of what your actual input data looks like after pivoting