# C# GenericParserAdapter is reading CSV Column name as Column1

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I am trying to use [GenericParserAdapter](https://github.com/AndrewRissing/GenericParsing) to read a CSV file into `DataTable`. And `ColumnName` is returning an incorrect value.

```
var adapter = new GenericParsing.GenericParserAdapter(outputFile.PathName);
DataTable dt = adapter.GetDataTable();
```

`dt.Columns[0].ColumnName` returns `"Column1"` which is not the actual name of that column. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you importing using Oledb?  If so did you specify in the connection string that the data had header a header row?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this:

[reading a CSV into a Datatable without knowing the structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569777/reading-a-csv-into-a-datatable-without-knowing-the-structure)

it would appear that you need to set the parser FirstRowHasHeader = true

I am not sure if this can be done in your constructor, or if you will need to split

```
var adapter = new GenericParsing.GenericParserAdapter(outputFile.PathName);
```

Into multiple lines and define the parser attributes after instantiation.